# Help in formulating sql query

Tags: sql

Here is my scenario

> Table 1:    GID ||  Info1
>
> Table 2:    GID ||  Tb1GID (refers
>   to GID of Table1) || Info2
>
> Table 3:    GID ||  Info3
>
> Table 4:    GID ||  Tb2GID (refers to
>   GID of Table2 || Tb3GID (refers to
>   Table3 GID || Value

Now I have to build an sql query to get the value, given a particular Info1, Info2, Info3.
Essentially, I have to get the GID, of table 1 using info1, GID of table to , by mapping info2 and GID of table 1. And then get the GID of table 3 using info 3. And combine these to GIDs to get the value in table 4.

What is the most optimal way of constructing an sql query for this one?

Comment: What queries have you gotten so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just join the tables on the id:s and match the info values in the condition:

```
select
  t4.Value
from
  [Table 1] as t1
  inner join [Table 2] as t2 on t2.Tb1GID = t1.GID
  inner join [Table 4] as t4 on t4.Tb2GID = t2.GID
  inner join [Table 3] as t3 on t3.GID = t4.Tb3GID
where
  t1.Info1 = @Info1 and
  t2.Info2 = @Info2 and
  t3.Info3 = @Info3
```

This communicates most clearly how the relations work, giving the query planner the best information to work with.

Comment: You can also move the WHERE clauses for `t2` and `t3` into their respective JOINs.